# How many users in a network

Tags: civimember, evaluating-civicrm, install

We are a non-profit transition movement in Norway. If we as ha "head office" sign up for a user license, will all our grasrootgroups (=neigbourhood) around in Norway be able to use the same license?

Answer (score 3):

First of all welcome to CiviCRM :)

As CiviCRM is published under the free [GNU AGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html) license there are no licensing costs and you do not even have to sign up. All your grasrootgroups can use your database or get their own copy /environment of CiviCRM (depending on your use case / requirements).